# Adding Texture with Weight Paint Doesnt show

Tags: texture-painting, weight-painting, vertex-colors

I am creating a highlands environment and trying to add a texture of a road by drawing on a plane with weight paint. I have two textures connected into a mix shader with a noise texture, coloramp plugged into factor. With an additional third texture, of a mud road, connected into a second mix shader. Before, I used to create Vertex Colour group (eg. "road") to paint the desired area with weight paint and use Attribute node with the attribute name as vertex colour group ("road") and the texture would show without any problem but now it doesn't work. Can someone please help me here?

The plane is subdivided by 100 and has subdivision and displacement modifiers.
It is not scaled.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I've never heard you could use a vertex group as a factor in a material, are you sure? Maybe you're confusing with vertex paint

Comment: Yes, you are correct it's vertex paint, not weight paint. Had to step away from the computer and go for a walk to realise it. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use vertex group as a factor in a material, but you can use vertex paint. Create an *Input > Attribute* node in the *Shader Editor* and type the vertex colors name.